# how to disable creating java heap dump after VM crashes?

Tags: java, freebsd, heap-dump

JVM runs on FreeBSD with 18Gb memory. creating core file takes about hour, which is very slow, so i need some way to disable it.

Comment: Something is really weird with your system.  Writing an 18Gb memory image to a file should not take 1 hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an OS crash dump then use ulimit to set the maximum core size to 0.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure this will work, but if you're using the HotSpot VM, try this in the arguments to the `java` command:

```
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/dev/null
```

If you want to turn off core dumps altogether, you can use the ulimit approach (make sure to use the -H flag to set the hard limit):

```
ulimit -c -H 0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really mean a core file, and not something specific to java, then you need to use the ulimit command to set the maximum core file size to something small.