# Preventing Cassandra from dumping hprof files

Tags: java, php, shell, jvm, cassandra

I would like to stop Cassandra from dumping hprof files as I do not require the use of them.

I also have very limited disk space (50GB out of 100 GB is used for data), and these files swallow up all the disk space before I can say "stop".

How should I go about it?

Is there a shell script that I could use to erase these files from time to time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens because Cassandra starts with `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` Java option. Which is good stuff if you want to analyze. Also, if you are getting lots of heap-dump that indicate that you should probably tune the memory available to Cassandra.

I haven't tried it. But to block this option, comment the following line in `$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra-env.sh`

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
```

Optionally, you may comment this block as well, but not really required, I think. This block is available in 1.0+ version I guess. I can't find this in 0.7.3.

```
# set jvm HeapDumpPath with CASSANDRA_HEAPDUMP_DIR
if [ "x$CASSANDRA_HEAPDUMP_DIR" != "x" ]; then
    JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:HeapDumpPath=$CASSANDRA_HEAPDUMP_DIR/cassandra-`date +%s`-pid$$.hprof"
fi
```

Let me know if this worked.

---

**Update**

> ...I guess it is JVM throwing it out when Cassandra crashes / shuts down. Any way to prevent that one from happening?

If you want to disable JVM heap-dump altogether, see here [how to disable creating java heap dump after VM crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556895/how-to-disable-creating-java-heap-dump-after-vm-crashes)

Comment: I was thinking of commenting it out too. But the hprof files I noticed did not follow the template "cassandra-NNN.hprof" but rather just "pid-XXX.hprof" so I guess it is JVM throwing it out when Cassandra crashes / shuts down. Any way to prevent that one from happening?

Comment: Commenting out the block in $CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra-env.sh did not really work. But thanks to the link and the .hprof removal cron job, everything is working fine now.
Thanks for the help once again.

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit i haven't used Cassandra, but from what i can tell, it shouldn't be dumping any hprof files unless you enable it at compile time, or the program experiences an OutofMemoryException. So try looking there.

in terms of a shell script, if the files are being dumped to a specific location you can use this command to delete all *.hprof files.

```
find /my/location/ -name *.hprof -delete
```

this is using the `-delete` directive from `find` that deletes all files that match the search. Look at the man page for find for more search options if you need to narrow it down more.

You can use `cron` to run a script at a given time, which would satisfy your "time to time" requirement, most linux distros have a cron installed, and work off of a `crontab` file. You can find out more about the crontab by using `man crontab`

Comment: Thanks! I have figured that out too!
Because actually the hprof files are coming out when I suspended the Cassandra instance, as they are named "pid-XXX.hprof" instead of "cassandra-XXX.hprof"
Thanks for the shell script. I shall implement them.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you update cassandra-env.sh to point to the heapdump path it will still not work. The reason was that from the upstart script /etc/init.d/cassandra there is this line which creates the default HeapDump path

```
start-stop-daemon -S -c cassandra -a /usr/sbin/cassandra -b -p "$PIDFILE" -- \
    -p "$PIDFILE" -H "$heap_dump_f" -E "$error_log_f" >/dev/null || return 2
```

I'm not an upstart expert but what I did was just removed the param which creates the duplicate. Another weird observation also when checking cassandra process via **ps aux** you'll notice that you'll see some parameters being written twice. If you source cassandra-env.sh and print $JVM_OPTS you'll notice those variables okay.