# Get rid of cassandra hprof

Tags: cassandra

I am having a Cassandra container which generates a hprof files if size 2-3 GB.

[Preventing Cassandra from dumping hprof files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108118/preventing-cassandra-from-dumping-hprof-files)
This link I followed but didn't help.Still, files are created and consume lots of space. I need to get rid of this hprof file.

Comment: I think the bigger question, is why are your Cassandra nodes crashing?  Fix that, and then it shouldn't generate those files in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If its an OOM error comment out

```
# Enable heap-dump if there's an OOM
#-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

in `jvm.options` or in older versions in `cassandra-env.sh`

```
#JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
```

It's worth investigating why your instances is OOMing, it shouldn't do that, most likely you need a larger heap size for your workload but there may be data modeling issues too.

If its a JVM crash I think your best bet is something like `-XX:HeapDumpPath=/dev/null`

Comment: Hi Chris Thanks for your response but as I told I tried exactly what you told meaning this one but still hprof file is created .
 #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"

Comment: Will it be good to write a script that delete the file automatically .
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/dev/null I have not tried this.

Comment: if file is dumped to /dev/null you wont need to delete. I would strongly recommend finding out why its crashing, then you wont have dump file either.